# Navigating through a page using puppeteer

Tags: typescript, puppeteer

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";

export const getNigeriaPortsLineups = async () => {
  let browser;
  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      headless: false,
      timeout: 60000,
    });
    const width = 1920,
      height = 1080;

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width, height });
    await page.setUserAgent(
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
    );
    await page.goto("https://shippos.nigerianports.gov.ng/", {
      timeout: 60000,
    });

    await page.evaluate(async () => {
      let nextButton = document.querySelector("#Apapa2_next") as HTMLElement;
      const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("#Apapa2 tbody tr");
      const sugarRows = Array.from(tableRows).map((row) => {
        return Array.from(row.querySelectorAll("td")).map((cell) =>
          cell.textContent.trim()
        );
      });

      let count = 0;
      while (count <= 4) {
        console.log(count);
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
        nextButton.click()
        
        count++;
      }

      // while (nextButton && !nextButton.classList.contains("disabled")) {
      //   nextButton.click();
      //   await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)); // Wait for a second before clicking again
      // }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } finally {
    // if (browser) await browser.close();
  }
};
```

I'm encountering an issue with Puppeteer while attempting to navigate through multiple pages of a table by clicking the "Next" button. Despite having a loop to click the button multiple times, the click event only seems to occur once. Despite logging the count variable, which tracks the number of times the button should be clicked, it appears that the loop iterates the correct number of times, but the click event does not repeat accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the next button is removed and replaced after each click, resulting in the old query result becoming stale (removed from the document). Try re-querying it on each click.

Here's an example that also cleans up the logic a bit and scrapes all data:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^22.2.0

const url = "<Your URL>";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto(url, {
    waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
    timeout: 120_000,
  });
  await page.waitForSelector("#Apapa2_next");
  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const data = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      data.push(
        ...[...document.querySelectorAll("#Apapa2 tbody tr")].map(row =>
          [...row.querySelectorAll("td")].map(cell =>
            cell.textContent.trim()
          )
        )
      );

      const nextBtn = document.querySelector("#Apapa2_next");

      if (nextBtn && !nextBtn.classList.contains("disabled")) {
        nextBtn.click();
      }
      else {
        break;
      }
    }

    return data;
  });
  console.table(data);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Now, the data seems to be available in the static HTML, so I'd use fetch and Cheerio rather than Puppeteer for this:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const url = "<Your URL>";

fetch(url)
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw Error(res.statusText);
    }

    return res.text();
  })
  .then(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const data = [...$("#Apapa2 tbody tr")].map(e =>
      [...$(e).find("td")].map(e => $(e).text().trim())
    );
    console.table(data);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Here's a quick benchmark on my machine:

Puppeteer:

```
real 0m20.965s
user 0m2.222s
sys  0m0.802s
```

Cheerio:

```
real 0m5.061s
user 0m0.547s
sys  0m0.042s
```

Fetch + Cheerio destroys Puppeteer here in every respect (simpler code, faster). One way to bring back some respectability to Puppeteer is to block JS and requests, and just focus on getting the data from the raw HTML response:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const url = "<Your URL>";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on("request", req =>
    req.url() === url ? req.continue() : req.abort()
  );
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const data = await page.$$eval("#Apapa2 tbody tr", els =>
    els.map(row =>
      [...row.querySelectorAll("td")].map(cell =>
        cell.textContent.trim()
      )
    )
  );
  console.table(data);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Time:

```
real 0m5.047s
user 0m0.839s
sys  0m0.230s
```

Much better. Faster and no need to worry about button clicking. This can be handy if your fetch requests are blocked.

If you're curious to read more about the techniques used here to speed up and simplify the script (not sleeping, using domcontentloaded, blocking JS and resources, avoiding DOM manipulation, using Fetch and Cheerio instead of Puppeteer) are described in detail in my [blog post on Puppeteer antipatterns](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/).